# Grant user access only to specific tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to grant a user access only to specific tables and I want to do it with least administrative effort. All tables are located in a database call 'Reporting'. And I only want the user to access tables which contain the word 'Finance'. Any idea how I could do it with least administrative effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this assumes that you have already created the user on the server/database but a simple script should help

```
USE [Database]
GO

SELECT
 'GRANT SELECT 
  ON [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + '] 
  TO [InsertUser]'
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name LIKE '%something%';
```

and run the results in a new query window.  You could probably create a stored proc to do it as well to save for the future and just pass in the user and table name